# Android webview and load different pages inside the app

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview

I have a question about webview. I'll try my best to explain.

I have a website and I want to display that website with webview (all the files are loaded from the app itself and not from the web).

I got it to work but I'm facing a problem while loading other files.

I have a calculator for January (html) and I got it to work fine, but for February, for example, it loads the same data inserted in January.

I tried to create 12 different folders, each folder with it own calculator files so it loads separate html/css but it still doesn't work how it should, which is loads different data on each month.

I have this code I found on the internet (I have no coding experience on this whatsoever by the way, I just try to self learn and try my best to make it work somehow).

Android manifest:

```xml
<manifest
    package="com.example.com"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="app"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.com.MainActivity"
            android:label="app" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main activity layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```java
package com.example.com;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I know it refers to INTERNET in there but I don't know how to make it work without that since it gives errors and won't compile if I remove those lines.

Comment: Updated the java class You can try running it using the same

Comment: I'm sorry but, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting?

Comment: I posted a new question below. It didn't let me post the full explanation in here.